# Is it possible to hide hyperlink from PDF when printed on paper using XSL FO

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm creating a PDF and there are a couple of hyperlinks that have text like "Click here to open". These texts are meaningless when printed on paper. Is it possible to hide those links when the PDF gets printed on paper? I'm using apache fop 0.20.x (I'm not sure about the version but it is old)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the hyperlinks as PDF link annotations. All annotations have a "print" property. You can set this to false. Here is an [example](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=220&t=Creating_Alternative_PDF_Content_For_Screen_and_Print) of doing something more complicated with one of our products but you will be able to do the same thing in XSL-FO too.